Paho Java Mqttv5 Connection lost (32109) to Azure IoT Hub
I have a Java MQTTv5 client using Paho library v1.2.6
I am sure that all credential are correct and accurate.
I have tried using mosquitto_pub (v2.0.18) and MQTTBox to connect and published to the Azure Iot Hub port 8883 So I assumed I have the correct credential and cert.
I have search through Paho Github and also stackoverflow and it seems to be fix in previous version but yet surface again in later version.
When I use my Java client to connect throws the following errors:
Connection lost (32109) - java.io.EOFException<br/>
        at<br/>org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.CommsReceiver.run(CommsReceiver.java:196)<br/>
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)<br/>
Caused by: java.io.EOFException<br/>
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:267)<br/>
        at<br/> org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.wire.MqttInputStream.readMqttWireMessage(MqttInputStream.java:96)<br/>
        at<br/> org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.CommsReceiver.run(CommsReceiver.java:139)<br/>
        ... 1 more<br/>

I have also run debug for the paho
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:01 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.MqttAsyncClient MqttAsyncClient<br/>
FINE: dio: <init> ClientID=dio ServerURI=ssl://mura-iot.azure-devices.net:8883 PersistenceType=org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.persist.MemoryPersistence@6ad21b4b<br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:01 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.CommsTokenStore <Init><br/>
FINE: dio: <><br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:01 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.ClientState <Init><br/>
FINER: dio: <br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:01 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.ClientState restoreState<br/>
FINE: dio: ><br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:01 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.MqttAsyncClient connect<br/>
FINE: dio: cleanStart=true connectionTimeout=300 TimekeepAlive=60 userName=mura-iot.azure-devices.net/dio/?api-version=2021-04-12 password=[notnull] will=[null] userContext=null callback=null<br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:01 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.MqttAsyncClient createNetworkModules<br/>
FINE: dio: URI=ssl://mura-iot.azure-devices.net:8883<br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:01 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.MqttAsyncClient createNetworkModule<br/>
FINE: dio: URI=ssl://mura-iot.azure-devices.net:8883<br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:01 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.MqttAsyncClient createNetworkModules<br/>
FINE: dio: <<br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:01 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.ClientComms connect<br/>
FINE: dio: state=CONNECTING<br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:01 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.CommsTokenStore open<br/>
FINE: dio: ><br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:01 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.Token waitForCompletion<br/>
FINE: dio: key=null wait max=5,000 token=key=null ,topics= ,usercontext=org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.MqttAsyncClient@2d75c9bc ,isComplete=false ,isNotified=false ,exception=null ,actioncallback=org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.ConnectActionListener@f9664ad<br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:01 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.ClientComms connectBG:run<br/>
FINE: dio: ><br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:01 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.CommsTokenStore getOutstandingDelTokens<br/>
FINE: dio: ><br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:01 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.Token waitForResponse<br/>
FINE: dio: >key=null timeout=5,000 sent=false completed=false hasException=false response=null token=key=null ,topics= ,usercontext=org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.MqttAsyncClient@2d75c9bc ,isComplete=false ,isNotified=false ,exception=null ,actioncallback=org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.ConnectActionListener@f9664ad<br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:01 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.CommsTokenStore saveToken<br/>
FINE: dio: key=Con message=MqttConnect [properties=MqttProperties [validProperties=[17, 24, 33, 39, 34, 25, 23, 38, 21, 22]], willProperties=MqttProperties [validProperties=[24, 1, 2, 8, 9, 38, 3]], info=0, clientId=dio, reservedByte=false, cleanStart=true, willMessage=null, userName=mura-iot.azure-devices.net/dio/?api-version=2021-04-12, password=[83, 104, 97, 114, 101, 100, 65, 99, 99, 101, 115, 115, 83, 105, 103, 110, 97, 116, 117, 114, 101, 32, 115, 114, 61, 97, 108, 118, 105, 110, 45, 105, 111, 116, 46, 97, 122, 117, 114, 101, 45, 100, 101, 118, 105, 99, 101, 115, 46, 110, 101, 116, 37, 50, 70, 100, 101, 118, 105, 99, 101, 115, 37, 50, 70, 100, 105, 111, 100, 101, 38, 115, 105, 103, 61, 79, 37, 50, 66, 56, 67, 106, 117, 65, 88, 66, 101, 97, 106, 103, 101, 101, 56, 121, 51, 90, 97, 112, 103, 97, 65, 122, 66, 107, 109, 88, 57, 37, 50, 70, 87, 113, 88, 122, 76, 85, 66, 122, 114, 71, 104, 89, 37, 51, 68, 38, 115, 101, 61, 49, 55, 51, 54, 49, 52, 57, 50, 56, 57], keepAliveInterval=60, willDestination=null, mqttVersion=5]<br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:01 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.Token waitForResponse<br/>
FINE: dio: key=null wait max=5,000<br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:01 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.CommsTokenStore saveToken<br/>
FINE: dio: key=Con token=org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.MqttToken@75bfff01<br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:01 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.TCPNetworkModule start<br/>
FINE: dio: connect to host mura-iot.azure-devices.net port 8,883 timeout 300,000<br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:02 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.CommsReceiver start<br/>
FINE: dio: starting<br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:02 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.CommsReceiver run<br/>
FINE: dio: network read message<br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:02 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.ClientState get<br/>
FINE: dio: wait for new work or for space in the inflight window<br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:03 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.CommsCallback run<br/>
FINE: dio: wait for workAvailable<br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:03 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.ClientComms internalSend<br/>
FINE: dio: 200<br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:03 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.ClientState send<br/>
FINE: dio: pending send key=0 message MqttConnect [properties=MqttProperties [validProperties=[17, 24, 33, 39, 34, 25, 23, 38, 21, 22]], willProperties=MqttProperties [validProperties=[24, 1, 2, 8, 9, 38, 3]], info=0, clientId=dio, reservedByte=false, cleanStart=true, willMessage=null, userName=mura-iot.azure-devices.net/dio/?api-version=2021-04-12, password=[83, 104, 97, 114, 101, 100, 65, 99, 99, 101, 115, 115, 83, 105, 103, 110, 97, 116, 117, 114, 101, 32, 115, 114, 61, 97, 108, 118, 105, 110, 45, 105, 111, 116, 46, 97, 122, 117, 114, 101, 45, 100, 101, 118, 105, 99, 101, 115, 46, 110, 101, 116, 37, 50, 70, 100, 101, 118, 105, 99, 101, 115, 37, 50, 70, 100, 105, 111, 100, 101, 38, 115, 105, 103, 61, 79, 37, 50, 66, 56, 67, 106, 117, 65, 88, 66, 101, 97, 106, 103, 101, 101, 56, 121, 51, 90, 97, 112, 103, 97, 65, 122, 66, 107, 109, 88, 57, 37, 50, 70, 87, 113, 88, 122, 76, 85, 66, 122, 114, 71, 104, 89, 37, 51, 68, 38, 115, 101, 61, 49, 55, 51, 54, 49, 52, 57, 50, 56, 57], keepAliveInterval=60, willDestination=null, mqttVersion=5]<br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:03 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.CommsTokenStore saveToken<br/>
FINE: dio: key=Con message=MqttConnect [properties=MqttProperties [validProperties=[17, 24, 33, 39, 34, 25, 23, 38, 21, 22]], willProperties=MqttProperties [validProperties=[24, 1, 2, 8, 9, 38, 3]], info=0, clientId=dio, reservedByte=false, cleanStart=true, willMessage=null, userName=mura-iot.azure-devices.net/dio/?api-version=2021-04-12, password=[83, 104, 97, 114, 101, 100, 65, 99, 99, 101, 115, 115, 83, 105, 103, 110, 97, 116, 117, 114, 101, 32, 115, 114, 61, 97, 108, 118, 105, 110, 45, 105, 111, 116, 46, 97, 122, 117, 114, 101, 45, 100, 101, 118, 105, 99, 101, 115, 46, 110, 101, 116, 37, 50, 70, 100, 101, 118, 105, 99, 101, 115, 37, 50, 70, 100, 105, 111, 100, 101, 38, 115, 105, 103, 61, 79, 37, 50, 66, 56, 67, 106, 117, 65, 88, 66, 101, 97, 106, 103, 101, 101, 56, 121, 51, 90, 97, 112, 103, 97, 65, 122, 66, 107, 109, 88, 57, 37, 50, 70, 87, 113, 88, 122, 76, 85, 66, 122, 114, 71, 104, 89, 37, 51, 68, 38, 115, 101, 61, 49, 55, 51, 54, 49, 52, 57, 50, 56, 57], keepAliveInterval=60, willDestination=null, mqttVersion=5]<br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:03 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.CommsTokenStore saveToken<br/>
FINE: dio: key=Con token=org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.MqttToken@75bfff01<br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:03 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.ClientState get<br/>
FINE: dio: new work or ping arrived <br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:03 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.CommsSender run<br/>
FINE: dio: network send key=Con msg=MqttConnect [properties=MqttProperties [validProperties=[17, 24, 33, 39, 34, 25, 23, 38, 21, 22]], willProperties=MqttProperties [validProperties=[24, 1, 2, 8, 9, 38, 3]], info=0, clientId=dio, reservedByte=false, cleanStart=true, willMessage=null, userName=mura-iot.azure-devices.net/dio/?api-version=2021-04-12, password=[83, 104, 97, 114, 101, 100, 65, 99, 99, 101, 115, 115, 83, 105, 103, 110, 97, 116, 117, 114, 101, 32, 115, 114, 61, 97, 108, 118, 105, 110, 45, 105, 111, 116, 46, 97, 122, 117, 114, 101, 45, 100, 101, 118, 105, 99, 101, 115, 46, 110, 101, 116, 37, 50, 70, 100, 101, 118, 105, 99, 101, 115, 37, 50, 70, 100, 105, 111, 100, 101, 38, 115, 105, 103, 61, 79, 37, 50, 66, 56, 67, 106, 117, 65, 88, 66, 101, 97, 106, 103, 101, 101, 56, 121, 51, 90, 97, 112, 103, 97, 65, 122, 66, 107, 109, 88, 57, 37, 50, 70, 87, 113, 88, 122, 76, 85, 66, 122, 114, 71, 104, 89, 37, 51, 68, 38, 115, 101, 61, 49, 55, 51, 54, 49, 52, 57, 50, 56, 57], keepAliveInterval=60, willDestination=null, mqttVersion=5]<br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:03 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.ClientState notifySentBytes<br/>
FINE: dio: sent bytes count=14<br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:03 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.ClientState notifySentBytes<br/>
FINE: dio: sent bytes count=207<br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:03 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.wire.MqttOutputStream write<br/>
FINE: dio: Sent MqttConnect [properties=MqttProperties [validProperties=[17, 24, 33, 39, 34, 25, 23, 38, 21, 22]], willProperties=MqttProperties [validProperties=[24, 1, 2, 8, 9, 38, 3]], info=0, clientId=dio, reservedByte=false, cleanStart=true, willMessage=null, userName=mura-iot.azure-devices.net/dio/?api-version=2021-04-12, password=[83, 104, 97, 114, 101, 100, 65, 99, 99, 101, 115, 115, 83, 105, 103, 110, 97, 116, 117, 114, 101, 32, 115, 114, 61, 97, 108, 118, 105, 110, 45, 105, 111, 116, 46, 97, 122, 117, 114, 101, 45, 100, 101, 118, 105, 99, 101, 115, 46, 110, 101, 116, 37, 50, 70, 100, 101, 118, 105, 99, 101, 115, 37, 50, 70, 100, 105, 111, 100, 101, 38, 115, 105, 103, 61, 79, 37, 50, 66, 56, 67, 106, 117, 65, 88, 66, 101, 97, 106, 103, 101, 101, 56, 121, 51, 90, 97, 112, 103, 97, 65, 122, 66, 107, 109, 88, 57, 37, 50, 70, 87, 113, 88, 122, 76, 85, 66, 122, 114, 71, 104, 89, 37, 51, 68, 38, 115, 101, 61, 49, 55, 51, 54, 49, 52, 57, 50, 56, 57], keepAliveInterval=60, willDestination=null, mqttVersion=5]<br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:03 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.ClientState notifySent<br/>
FINE: dio: key=Con<br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:03 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.Token notifySent<br/>
FINE: dio: > key=Con<br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:03 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.ClientState get<br/>
FINE: dio: wait for new work or for space in the inflight window<br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:03 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.CommsReceiver run<br/>
FINE: dio: Stopping due to IOException<br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:03 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.ClientComms shutdownConnection<br/>
FINE: dio: state=DISCONNECTING<br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:03 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.CommsCallback stop<br/>
FINE: dio: stopping<br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:03 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.CommsCallback stop<br/>
FINE: dio: notify workAvailable and wait for run<br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:03 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.CommsCallback stop<br/>
FINE: dio: stopped<br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:03 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.CommsCallback run<br/>
FINE: dio: notify spaceAvailable<br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:03 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.CommsReceiver stop<br/>
FINE: dio: stopping<br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:03 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.CommsReceiver stop<br/>
FINE: dio: stopped<br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:03 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.CommsTokenStore quiesce<br/>
FINE: dio: resp=Client is currently disconnecting (32102)<br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:03 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.ClientComms handleOldTokens<br/>
FINE: dio: ><br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:03 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.ClientState resolveOldTokens<br/>
FINE: dio: reason Connection lost (32109) - java.io.EOFException<br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:03 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.CommsTokenStore getOutstandingTokens<br/>
FINE: dio: ><br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:03 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.CommsTokenStore removeToken<br/>
FINE: dio: key=Con<br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:03 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.ClientState disconnected<br/>
FINE: dio: disconnected<br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:03 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.ClientState clearState<br/>
FINE: dio: ><br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:03 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.CommsTokenStore clear<br/>
FINE: dio: > 0 tokens<br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:03 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.ClientState clearConnectionState<br/>
FINE: dio: Clearing Connection State (Topic Aliases)<br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:03 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.CommsSender stop<br/>
FINE: dio: stopping sender<br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:03 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.ClientState notifyQueueLock<br/>
FINE: dio: notifying queueLock holders<br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:03 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.CommsSender stop<br/>
FINE: dio: stopped<br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:03 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.ClientState get<br/>
FINE: dio: new work or ping arrived <br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:03 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.TimerPingSender stop<br/>
FINE: dio: stop<br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:03 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.ClientState get<br/>
FINE: dio: no outstanding flows and not connected<br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:03 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.ClientComms shutdownConnection<br/>
FINE: dio: state=DISCONNECTED<br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:03 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.CommsSender run<br/>
FINE: dio: get message returned null, stopping}<br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:03 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.CommsCallback handleActionComplete<br/>
FINE: dio: callback and notify for key=Con<br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:03 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.CommsSender run<br/>
FINE: dio: <<br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:03 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.Token notifyComplete<br/>
FINE: dio: >key=Con response=null excep=Connection lost (32109) - java.io.EOFException<br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:03 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.CommsCallback fireActionEvent<br/>
FINE: dio: call onSuccess key=Con<br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:03 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.Token markComplete<br/>
FINE: dio: >key=null response=null excep=Connection lost (32109) - java.io.EOFException<br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:03 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.Token notifyComplete<br/>
FINE: dio: >key=null response=null excep=Connection lost (32109) - java.io.EOFException<br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:03 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.CommsReceiver run<br/>
FINE: dio: <<br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:03 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.Token waitForResponse<br/>
FINE: dio: failed with exception<br/>
Connection lost (32109) - java.io.EOFException<br/>
    at org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.CommsReceiver.run(CommsReceiver.java:196)<br/>
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)<br/>
Caused by: java.io.EOFException<br/>
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:267)<br/>
    at org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.wire.MqttInputStream.readMqttWireMessage(MqttInputStream.java:96)<br/>
    at org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.CommsReceiver.run(CommsReceiver.java:139)<br/>
    ... 1 more<br/>
<br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:03 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.MqttAsyncClient disconnect<br/>
FINE: dio: > quiesceTimeout=5,000 userContext=null callback=null<br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:03 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.ClientComms disconnect<br/>
FINE: dio: failed: already disconnected<br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:03 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.MqttAsyncClient disconnect<br/>
FINE: dio: < exception<br/>
Client is disconnected (32101)<br/>
    at org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.ExceptionHelper.createMqttException(ExceptionHelper.java:32)<br/>
    at org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.ClientComms.disconnect(ClientComms.java:554)<br/>
    at org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.MqttAsyncClient.disconnect(MqttAsyncClient.java:842)<br/>
    at org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.MqttAsyncClient.disconnect(MqttAsyncClient.java:818)<br/>
    at mqPackage.MQTTConnection.closeConnection(MQTTConnection.java:242)<br/>
    at mqPackage.MQTTConnection.connect(MQTTConnection.java:270)<br/>
    at mqPackage.MQTTHandler.run(MQTTHandler.java:1016)<br/>
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)<br/>
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)<br/>
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)<br/>
<br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:03 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.MqttAsyncClient close<br/>
FINE: dio: <<br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:03 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.CommsTokenStore clear<br/>
FINE: dio: > 0 tokens<br/>
Oct 09, 2024 11:59:03 AM org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.MqttAsyncClient close<br/>
FINE: dio: ><br/>

I have the following codes:
    public void setConOpts() throws Exception {

        m_conOpts.setServerURIs(new String[] { m_ip });

        if (m_userNameAuth) {
            m_conOpts.setUserName(m_username);
            m_conOpts.setPassword(m_password.getBytes());
        }

        m_conOpts.setConnectionTimeout(300);
        m_conOpts.setCleanStart(m_setCleanStart);

        if (m_trustServerCert || m_validateServerCert || m_twoWaySSL) {
            m_conOpts.setSocketFactory(TLS.getSocketFactory(m_trustServerCert, m_validateServerCert, m_serverCertPath, m_twoWaySSL, m_keystorePath, m_keystorePwd));
        }

    }

I have the following code for connect:
                this.v5Client = new MqttAsyncClient(m_ip, m_clientID, m_persistence);
                this.v5Client.setCallback(mqH);

                IMqttToken connectToken = this.v5Client.connect(m_conOpts);
                connectToken.waitForCompletion(actionTimeout);

I have tried taking out most of the connection options but it still didn't work. I am thinking it might be some compatibilities paho mqttv5 to Azure Iot Hub v3.1.1
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot/iot-mqtt-connect-to-iot-hub
*The username and password in debug log is not the actual one

Note that the logs contain a username and password (these are included in the connect packet) so assume your token is compromised (if you did not edit it before posting). Based on this the token neds to be in the Authentication Data property (not the password). I would also note that v5 appears to be deprecated on IoT Hub (so you may be better sticking with v3).

@Brits Yea I changed the username and password before i posted it, Thanks for the token compromised heads up. Could you further explain what you mean by the token needs to be in the Authentication Data property? Is there any thing I can do on my client application?

setAuthenticationMethod and setAuthenticationData on MqttConnectionOptions. This sets up properties that are included in the CONNECT packet.

Paho MQTTv3 library works with Azure Iot Hut therefore I have added Paho MQTTv3 library into the application and toggle between 3 and 5 as needed.
